# Save an Object to Database in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I created a code first project in which there is a post model and person model:

```
public class post
{
    [Key]
    public int postId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public virtual person sender { get; set; }
}

public class person
{
    [Key]
    public int personId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a post, in which sender persons' info exists but person is defined as an object. How can I insert an existing person to a post when I create a new post? Actually I can only insert some fields like int, string etc. by taking value from views but in this case it is not a value it is an object, how can I insert the data?

e.g.
code:

```
ViewBag.personlist = new SelectList(db.persons,"personId","name");
```

view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sender, (SelectList)ViewBag.personlist, "select item")
```

In database there is no sender item but person_postId, because of this reason dropdownlistfor send NULL value, how can I deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you need to add the personID foreign key to your post model:

```
 public class post
{
    [Key]
    public int postId { get; set; }
    public int personId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public virtual person sender { get; set; }
}
```

As it stands you have a navigation property but no foreign key to associate the post with a person.  The following line:

```
public virtual person sender { get; set; }
```

sets your navigation property, however it needs an personID from the person model to be a field in the post model so that there is a recorded link between that person and the post.  Entity Framework will automatically label personID as a foreign key by virtue of having the navigation property set.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I add a field like PersonId to my model, and it works. But my question is "if I should add personId to the model why I put -public virtual person sender- ?" 

I suppose that "person sender" will result in something like personId, actually MVC create such a column in db but by using medel I couldnot reach the created column. So what is the function of "person sender"?

Comment: The person sender line is a navigation property, it tells entity framework that you are linking this model to another model, entity framework will then look at the properties of your model to find a key that links to the other model.  So originally it was looking for one but not finding anything, once you had personID it will find that ID and can see that this ID is present in the person model.  So it knows to use this as the link to the model.  Effectively for you the 'person sender' line is just telling EF there should be a link to the other model, please look for a key to link it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I got the point. Normally because names are not matching entity framework couldnot match the navigation property with PK, for this reason I use [ForeignKey] keyword like the following way, ant it works! 
-----------------
public int selectedPersonId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("selectedPersonId")]
public virtual person sender { get; set; }----------

Comment: No problem.  Is there a reason why you want to use a different name for the field?  If there isn't I suggest you use the same field name so as to avoid future complications.  Of course if you need the field to be named differently you will have to tell EF that this is the foreign key, which is what you have done.  If my answer helped please mark as answer.  Good luck!